# Call last seven day on QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I use this comand

```
  lpad( aggregate('FIRELAYER','count',"CITYwhithFIRE",(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('0 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('1 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('2 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('3 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('4 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('5 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('6 day')))
+(to_date("DateHourWhenfirehappens")=to_date(to_date(@atlas_pagename)-to_interval('7 day')))),4,0)
```

for call last seven days of fire points on QIGS Atlas, I would like to know, if there is another simpler way to do this same command.

Table example

[image]

The resul is a number of fire, on last seven days 
from the day of atlas page name

Comment: Can you share an example of your attribute table?

Comment: ............done